# Symfony3 yml entity mappings inside bundle, entity classes outside bundle

Tags: orm, doctrine-orm, symfony, php-7

I have divided my code into AppBundle that will hold anything related to framework (including doctrine stuff), and another namespace for business logic.

So basically I have such file structure:

```
└── src
    ├── AppBundle
    │   └── Resources
    │       └── config
    │           └── doctrine
    │               ├── Attributes.orm.yml
    │               └── User.orm.yml
    └── Logic
        └── User
            ├── Attributes.php
            └── User.php
```

And mappings looks like that:

```
Logic\User\User:
    type: entity
    table: user
    id: (...)
    fields: (...)
    embedded:
        attributes:
            class: Logic\User\Attributes
```

And attributes mapping:

```
Logic\User\Attributes:
    type: embeddable
    fields: (...)
```

Now, when I try to update schema, i get error:

```
./sf doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql


  [Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\MappingException]  
  Class 'AppBundle\Entity\Attributes' does not exist
```

So basically mappings are found and being processed, but symfony ignores namespaces for the classes that i wrote inside mappings, and tries to find it in bundle entity directory. What do I have to do to fix it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doctrine mapping configurations are defined here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html#mapping-configuration

In particular you will want to set dir to your mapping directory and prefix to the entity namespace.

orm:
        default_entity_manager:       default
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%

```
    entity_managers:

        default:
            connection: default
            mappings:
                CeradOrgBundle:    ~
                CeradUserBundle:   ~
                CeradPersonBundle: ~

        games:
           connection: games
           mappings:
                CeradGameBundle: 
                    dir:    Resources/config/doctrine2
                    prefix: Cerad\Bundle\GameBundle\Doctrine\Entity
```

In the above example, I created two entity managers.  The default entity manager processes various bundles with the standard directly layout.

The games manager shows how to customize the mapping information.  In this case the orm files live in the doctrine2 directory instead of doctrine.

The prefix is what you are interested in.  Notice that these entities live under DoctrineEntity instead of just the normal Entity directory.

So set your prefix and you should be good to go.